# Postgresql merge/aggregate json column and return json object as output

Tags: json, postgresql

I am using Postgresql 9.6

I have a table, where my column is of type json.

```
create table test (
my_data json,
.
.
);
```

When queried, for each row the column is shown as json:

[image: Sample Data]

I want to aggregate the data, for sake of simplicity selected 2 columns only. I need to group by col1_data. I want like below:

[image: Expected Result]

I tried to use json_agg, but that will agregate and output as array of jsons.

```
select col1_data, json_agg(col2_data) as col2_data
from test
group by col1_data;
```

[image: Wrong output]

Can someone help to convert the array of json to json?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
select col1_data, json_agg(col2_element) as col2_data
from test, json_array_elements(col2_data) as col2_element
group by col1_data;
```

Alternatively, you can [write your own aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createaggregate.html) that concatenates json arrays.